# How to repopulate /etc/skel on plasma desktop environment?

Tags: arch-linux, plasma5

I deleted the contents of `/etc/skel`
because I wanted to get rid of some custom theming that was in there.
How do I repopulate it?
I ran `sudo pacman -S plasma`
but it is still empty.

Yes, I know they are hidden files. I set Dolphin to display hidden files, but there is still nothing in there, because I manually deleted everything.

My end goal is to get default Plasma theming...

System: Arch with Plasma Desktop

Comment: Is there anything specific to plasma in `/etc/skel`? On my Arch, I have files provided by `core/bash`, `community/mksh` and `extra/screen` packages. I have `plasma-desktop` installed, but that has added nothing to `/etc/skel`.

Comment: @terdon you are right. There is nothing Plasma-related in skel. My bad.

Comment: In any case, you should be able to get the defaults back by deleting any plasma related dot files from your home did or frome `~/.config`. Have you checked those? Try renaming them.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. I started a new thread: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/744523/kde-plasma-5-27-breeze-light-theme-colors-messed-up

Answer (score 1):

You can repopulate the files from the `/etc/skel` directory by reinstalling all packages that contain the directory:

```
sudo pacman -S $(pacman -Qoq /etc/skel)
```