# KDE Plasma 5.27 Breeze light theme -- colors messed up

Tags: plasma5

Something is messed up with the colors in the default Breeze theme.

In the upper left of the screenshot, you can see that the text box has a black background, which makes the text invisible.

And at the bottom, you can see a black window frame.

Once upon a time, I installed GDM display manager, which pulled in Gnome-shell as a dependency. I removed both, but the color issue did not go away.

```
System:
  Host: Arch Kernel: 6.1.26-1-lts arch: x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: KDE Plasma
    v: 5.27.4 Distro: Arch Linux
```

[image]

[image]